# Highlight current search result in vim

Tags: vim

In emacs, when you do a search, there will be one highlight color for all occurences in the buffer, and another color for the occurence that your cursor happens to be on. I was wondering if anyone knew about similar behavior in vim, a vim plugin, or even some ideas on how to accomplish it myself in vimscript.

(note, I already know about hl-IncSearch, which is close, but not what I am looking for)

Comment: Interesting question.  I'm not sure there is a concept of "current search result" in Vim.  The "next" and "previous" results are defined by the word the cursor is on.  You might be able to do special logic if your cursor is on a line/word/character, and bit is part of a hilight.

Comment: yeah... I don't have too much hope about it being built in for that reason, but there are a lot of great little plugins that handle things like that out there that can be hard to find.

Comment: Here's a page with some scripts that might get you started: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_all_search_pattern_matches

Comment: This functionality would be great as I often have troubles identifying which search result the cursor is on. For now, I use a couple of workarounds that might benefit someone else: `nnoremap n nzz`, which centers the search hit when pressing 'n', and `set cul`, which always keeps the current line highlighted.

Comment: I'd say the best solution for knowing which match is the current one would be to centre it on the screen: `nnoremap n nz.` and `nnoremap N Nz`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a built-in way to do what you want.

If I were to try to implement it myself... Well one way you could do it is by overriding `*`, `n` and `p` and combining it with something like [this function](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_word_to_find_cursor):

```
noremap n n:call HighlightNearCursor()<CR>
noremap p p:call HighlightNearCursor()<CR>
noremap * *:call HighlightNearCursor()<CR>

function HighlightNearCursor()
  if !exists("s:highlightcursor")
    match Todo /\k*\%#\k*/
    let s:highlightcursor=1
  else
    match None
    unlet s:highlightcursor
  endif
endfunction
```

I haven't tested it out, so this isn't a complete solution, but I think it is at least a viable approach.

**EDIT :** You will probably have to set some custom highlight colours. [This vimwiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words) gives some information about that, although I remember seeing a terser example *somewhere*.

**EDIT AGAIN:** Maybe a cleaner solution is to use [Mark.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666) in conjunction with the first technique. Then it would all boil down to something like:

```
noremap n \nn\m
noremap p \np\m
noremap * \n*\m
```

Comment: Thanks, definately what I am looking for. I'll accept this (and implement it) if nobody suggests an existing plugin in the next day or two

Comment: For me, this solution only triggers every other n/p-visited match.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you want to highlight all results in the buffer. You can say

```
:set hls
```

Which will turn on `hlsearch`. Then you can say

```
:set nohls  # turn off permanently
:noh        # turn off until next time you search.
```

You can also search for / highlight the word under the cursor with <kbd>*</kbd> (forwards) or <kbd>#</kbd> (backwards).

Comment: Not sure this matches what the OP is looking for.  They already know about how to hilight search results, but want to change the "currently selected" result's color.  The command invoked by the `*` key doesn't solve this - it will *change* the search pattern, which I don't think is what they are trying to do.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure how good a fit it was. But note that `hl-IncSearch` is different to `hlsearch`, and the `*`/`#` was just a bonus piece of text for others :)

Comment: yeah, Merlyn was right. I mentioned hl-IncSearch because that does what i want in the context of a s/// operation, but not for normal searches.

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote a vim plugin that does what you requested.

https://github.com/timakro/vim-searchant

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a real answer, but a simple way to get maybe 75% of what you want may be to just change the highlighting of the cursor.  The default gray cursor block doesn't contrast well with the default yellow of search highlights.  So just change cursor highlighting to (a) something that contrasts more with yellow and (2) also contrasts with other colors in your colorscheme.  For me something like this works pretty well:

```
highlight Cursor guifg=green guibg=red
```

For me the blinking red  cursor on first letter of current search match stands out pretty well.  Not as good as a full-blown solution, but dead-simple.  (I assume it works just as well in terminal Vim if you add those items to the `highlight` command but haven't tested it there.)